# Information gain using scikit.learn on Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, entropy

i have this issue as am working on decision trees using scikit.learn on Python. I would like to obtain better leaf for a chosen depth of my decision tree.

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=50000)
```

So this is my decision tree function and what i'm aiming to do is to choose the right information gain threshold to obtain better results. The default information gain threshold is zero so features with an information gain > to zero are chosen.

I want to fix the information gain threshold to be superior to a specefic number. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, this is not supported right now. You cannot set a lower bound on the reduction of impurity when looking for splits. It is always the one that maximizes the reduction that is picked, even if the improvement is close to 0.